# Missing `/usr/lib/libboost_unit_test_framework-mt.so' in Debian Testing

Tags: c++, boost, debian

I am trying to build my CMake project I was last working on a few months ago, but I get the following error message:

```
make[3]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/lib/libboost_unit_test_framework-mt.so', needed by `test/baumwelchtests'.  Stop.
```

Indeed, this file does not exist in `/usr/lib`, there is only `libboost_unit_test_framework.so`. What is the difference between normal version and the `-mt` version? I am pretty sure the -mt version was removed after one of the recent system upgrades (I am running Debian Testing, so there were quite a few changes after the latest stable release). How can I get my stuff to compile?

My CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
# Include subdirectories for headers
find_package( Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS unit_test_framework regex)

include_directories(${BaumWelch_SOURCE_DIR}/../../grzesLib/src
                    ${BaumWelch_SOURCE_DIR}/src 
                    ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
    add_definitions(-g -std=c++11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic -Wuninitialized)
endif()


# Create the unit tests executable
add_executable(
 baumwelchtests stockestimationtests.cpp forecasttest.cpp lagstest.cpp hiddenmarkovmodeltest.cpp stateindextest.cpp baumiterationtest.cpp baumwelchtest.cpp sampleparameters.cpp sdetest.cpp hmmgenerator.h
 # Key includes for setting up Boost.Test
 testrunner.cpp
 # Just for handy reference
 exampletests.cpp
)

# Link the libraries
target_link_libraries( baumwelchtests ${Boost_LIBRARIES} baumwelchlib grzeslib)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-mt` stands for mutlithreaded.

You can force CMake to link against regular boost libraries by setting `set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED OFF)`

But most likely you just need to install `libboost-test-dev`

Comment: This package is installed though.